# recorrer todos los ID de mi JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

ya e realizado dos preguntas anteriormente y es que sigo buscando una manera de resolverlo y creo que en esta la encontré solo que ahora no se como mostrar todos los índices ID de mi JSON primero asi es como realizo la consulta de mis JSON:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PedidosAlmacen WHERE Estado NOT IN ('Ingresados En Sucursal','En Transito a Sucursal','Recibido En Sucursal') AND ParaAlmacenID = '$ID_almacen' ORDER BY Fecha ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $productos=json_decode($row['Productos'],true);
 var_dump($productos);
}
```

**lo que me arroja es:**
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "557" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(19) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "557" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(19) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "557" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(19) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO" } [1]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "558" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO SAM" } } array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "557" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1002" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(19) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO" } [1]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(3) "558" ["codigo"]=> string(4) "1003" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(18) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO SAM" } }

**ahora sabiendo eso hice lo siguiente:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PedidosAlmacen WHERE Estado NOT IN ('Ingresados En Sucursal','En Transito a Sucursal','Recibido En Sucursal') AND ParaAlmacenID = '$ID_almacen' ORDER BY Fecha ASC";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$i=0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $productos=json_decode($row['Productos'],true);
 echo $productos[$i]["id"],$productos[$i]["cantidad"];
 $i++;
}
```

pensé en ponerle un $i para que incremente y triga todos pero solo trae los primeros: **5571 el ID y su cantidad** debería usar un foreach o algún ciclo para recórrelo antes de que termine?, digo loque me gustaría es que en ciclo del principal while se traiga el primer JSON **(** { [0]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "557" ["cantidad"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(19) "3 EN 1 DISEÑO MOTO" } } **)**

preguntas anteriores:

[Acceder a todos los índices de mi Array de una consulta Con PHP Y MySQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/545263/acceder-a-todos-los-%c3%adndices-de-mi-array-de-una-consulta-con-php-y-mysql)

[traer un JSON de una base de datos con Mysql y PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/545204/traer-un-json-de-una-base-de-datos-con-mysql-y-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$productos es un array compuesto de arrays en cada ciclo que no estas recorriendo completamente. Por lo tanto cambia esto:

```
$productos=json_decode($row['Productos'],true);
echo $productos[$i]["id"],$productos[$i]["cantidad"];
```

por esto:

```
$productos=json_decode($row['Productos'],true);
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    echo $producto["id"],$producto["cantidad"];
}
```

de esta forma recorremos correctamente los subarrays contenidos en cada array en cada ciclo.

Lo de la $i no hace falta ni funciona bien en este caso.

Ya nos diras si ahora te funciona.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda en verdad me atore todo el día con esto sabia que tenia que recorrerlos pero no sabia como hacerlo